# Java - RecyclerView прокручивается вверх при добавлении значений

Tags: java, android, recyclerview, recyclerview.adapter

Хочу реализовать бесконечный список. При добавлении значений, они появляются в списке, но он прокручивается вверх

Answer (score 1):

Проблема была в методе обновления RecyclerView. Я добавлял значения в Map и присваивал её RecyclerView. Нужно было просто обновить его после первого присваивания Map `recyclerview1.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();`